# FloatToStr returns imprecise value when FPU Control Word changed

Tags: delphi, floating-point

Im using Delphi 7 and now `FloatToStr(64)` returns

> 64,0000017441

when a different module is loaded in the same process that uses Direct3D code.

The return value is

> 64

as expected, when the other module is not active in the process.

Why does the Output of FloatToStr() change based on other unrelated code executed and what to do to always get a reliable and consistent string representation of a floating point value?

The difference in behaviour of FloatToStr() can be seen in the following sample code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program Project1;
uses
  SysUtils;
begin
  Writeln('FloatToStr(64) = ', FloatToStr(64));
  Set8087CW(Get8087CW and $FCFF);
  Writeln('FloatToStr(64) = ', FloatToStr(64));
end.
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What is "earlier", did you change versions?

Comment: without this hack https://github.com/aqrit/war2_ddraw/  works normally, with FloatToStr returns long values

Comment: Never, never ever post an image of your code. It's difficult to read, impossible to copy and paste for testing, and can't be read from most mobile devices. It's also much more difficult to post as an image than it is to just select, copy and paste into your question. So to make it clear, **never, never ever** post your code as an iimage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the foreign plugin code, in "display.cpp" in the code

```
hr = d3d->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hwnd, 
        D3DCREATE_NOWINDOWCHANGES | D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE,
        &d3dpp, &d3ddev );
```

add the flag "D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE" so that the code is:

```
hr = d3d->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hwnd, 
        D3DCREATE_NOWINDOWCHANGES | D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE | D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE,
        &d3dpp, &d3ddev );
```

If you leave out this code, Direct 3D changes the precision used by the FPU for the current thread and you will see less precise values.

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmiller/archive/2004/06/01/145596.aspx

The alternative (when you can't or don't want to change the other plugin code ) is to use explicit formating when displaying floating point values.

Use

```
   s:= FormatFloat('0.##', x);
```

instead of

```
   s:= FloatToStr(X);
```

This will always round the value to two decimal places and not show trailing zeros after the decimal separator. And it will not show any decimal separator, when the two highest digits are 0.

Another alternative would be to have your code run in a separate thread, since the FPU precision settings are per thread.

Another alternative would be to execute

```
 Reset8087CW;
```

in your code before calling FloatToStr(). However, this could mess with Direct3D and produce errors there.

Comment: "But seriously, it depresses me that you don't care enough to understand this" to me? Im not even a programmer and never will be

Answer (score 5):

To give a simple console application that replicates the behaviour you're seeing, as well as an explanation with some more details:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program Project1;
uses
  SysUtils;
begin
  Set8087CW(Get8087CW and $FCFF);
  Writeln('FloatToStr(64) = ', FloatToStr(64));
end.
```

Output:

```
FloatToStr(64) = 64.000001744411
```

Stepping through the debugger, the code for converting `64` to a decimal representation ends up calling

```
function _Pow10(val: Extended; Power: Integer): Extended;
```

with `val = 64`, `Power = 16` to calculate `64 * 10**16`. This then gets converted to an integer `640000000000000000`, from which decimal digits get extracted, and in which a decimal point gets placed. This would be just fine in the default FPU mode, where it would produce `640000000000000000` exactly, but in the FPU mode used here, less precision is available, not enough precision to represent that number. It gets rounded up to the nearest representable number, and the subsequent code to extract the decimals correctly sees that the last digits *aren't* `0`.

This issue is the subject of an unresolved QC report from 2004: [QC#7275](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=7275).

Comment: Note: This does not happen in current version (2.6.4) of Free Pascal. Would be interesting to know which versions of Delphi have that problem.

Comment: That's more like it. I would hope modern Delphi gets this right. What are you changing? The precision?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, the `$0300` bits control the precision. Unset means single precision (24-bit precision). I don't know what happens with any other Delphi versions.

Comment: Thanks. It's really depressing.

Comment: It's just the same in modern Delphi. Even worse, conversion from text to floating point on x64 call `InternalTextToExtended` which then calls `SetMXCSR` which is not threadsafe. So all such conversions have scope to leak floating point state from one thread to another. I told Emba about this years ago but they just won't fix it.

Comment: @NineBerry I think this afflicts all versions of Delphi. Mea culpa. I should not have presumed that Emba could write floating point code correctly. I apologise to everyone.

Comment: Of course, this C code `#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 unsigned int control_word_x87;
 control_word_x87 = __control87_2(_PC_24, MCW_PC, &control_word_x87, 0);
 printf("%.16f\n", 64.0); return 0;
}
` emits `64.0000000000000000` as you would hope